# get uid from angularfire list object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
{
 "books" : {
"-KxIQCyLuvaAE1Mv2RaF" : {
  "author" : "test",
  "title" : "Please work"
},



db.list('books').valueChanges().subscribe((data)=>{
  //some code
})
```

I would like to grab the uid of a book object so that I can pass it to another component and just load that single book. I have looked everywhere, and there seems to be no easy way to do this

---EDIT--

that does not give me the keys from firebase

```
db.list('books').valueChanges().subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(Object.keys(data));
})
```

results in

```
[18:55:47]  console.log: 0,1
```

I want the key:     -KxIQCyLuvaAE1Mv2RaF

--EDIT 2--

I should read documentation,

```
.valueChanges()
```

strips metadata from the objects. I need

```
.snapshotChanges()
```

Comment: This is just pure JS and has nothing to do with Angular or angularfire, so I'll mark this as a duplicate. Answer based on your code, you can access the key with: `Object.keys(data.books)[0]` like suggested in duplicate :)

Comment: Does not `.valueChanges()` return a "List" `[]` of the documents. Your console log would seem to indicate those "keys" are array indexes. So iterate the array returned and get the `Object.keys()` for each item.